# Linear Algebra - 2 planes intersecting in 1 point

Tags: linear-algebra

My Linear Algebra textbook claims that if given n planes, where n >= 3, they either:

1. don't intersect
2. Intersect in a single point
3. Intersect in a line
4. Are identical.

My question: How in the world do planes intersect in a single point? I cannot grasp it geometrically.

Comment: Two planes can't. n planes can.

Comment: Okay, but how do n planes intersect in a single point? I cannot grasp that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a picture of $3$ planes intersecting at a single point:

[image]

Notice that the intersection of *any two* of these planes is a line, but the intersection of *all three* is a single point.

Comment: Aah I see, thank you. So can n planes intersect at the midpoint in the same way?

Comment: Let's say we were to add a fourth plane to the above set.  Then there'd be two possibilities.  Either that plane contains the point of intersection of these three.  Then the intersection of all four is still that same point.  Or the new plane *doesn't* contain the point of intersection of these three planes.  Then the intersection of *all four* planes is the empty set.  That means that there are *no points* shared by all four planes.

Answer (score 0):

Take planes $OXY,OYZ,OZX$ (i.e. three axis planes in $\Bbb R^3$). They only intersect at $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you I see, that should have been obvious to me haha.